# Upgrading (mongodb) npm package major version in node.js project

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm, backend, node-modules

I am new in Node.js ,, I will start working in a project that was implemented years ago .. using Node.js , mongodb and angular 4 .

i checked the file package.json for the mongdb and i had found this value 
"mongodb": "^2.1.21"

I want to upgrade the application to use the latest version of mongodb , so i had run this command 
npm i mongodb@latest

but it gave me an error that the upgrade to the latest version which is  3.3.0-beta2 is invalid

so i changed the command into npm i mongodb@2.2.36 . Now i don't how to make it accept to update to the latest stable version of mongodb . and what are the changes that i need to do to my code to make sure it runs successfully .

also regarding the mongo db server , do i need to install the latest version to make my application run successfully after upgrading the mongodb node package ..? i did many investigations and couldn't reach to clear answer regarding this

Comment: What do you mean by you don't know how to make it accept latest stable version?

Comment: I tried to run the command (npm i mongodb@latest) which suppose to upgrade the package to the latest version but it gives an error ,, it accepts only when i wrote the same command with a certain version number which have the same major number of the already existing package (npm i mongodb@2.2.36)  @Ru Chern Chong

Comment: Try running `npm i --save mongodb` and see what version you get in your `package.json`. You should see `3.2.7`

Comment: I tried to run this command before running npm i mongodb@latest and it also upgraded to the latest minor version of the major version that already exists .. and run it now , and then checked the package.json file but nothing changed , i found that the version of mongodb is still  (^2.2.36)

Comment: in the following command is the message which was displayed after running the command u had sent

Comment: npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

Comment: i tried to run npm i mongodb@3.x but it gives an error  -- mongodb@3.2.7  invalid is invalid

Comment: Run `npm i --save mongodb@latest`

Comment: Thanks very much for your help . . it worked finally with this command  npm i --save mongodb@latest  which u mentioned ,, and now it is value in package.json "mongodb": "^3.3.0-beta2", ,, . additional question , how to know what are the updates in the code that I need to do for my project code to be compatible with this new mongodb version .

Comment: You got to read their changelog

Comment: would you send the link please ,, i found this one https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/tutorial/upgrade-config-servers-to-replica-set/  . but not sure it is the correct one

Comment: I will use this one: https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/releases

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your question, run

```
npm i --save mongodb@latest
```

to install and update the dependency in `package.json`.